# textfield font-size set issue

Tags: flash, flash-cs6

[image]

i tried to set a textfield font-size 200. When i click on the text field, there is no problem. but i focus out the text field, automatically is smaller problem occurs. refer a below image.

why this problem occur? i don't know how to solved. of course, when i run the program, there is no problem. But why in stage, automatically the font size smaller?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://getsatisfaction.com/adobe/topics/why_the_127px_fontsize_limit) is a discussion of the problem. But as I understood it have to be fixed for flash player 10.